# Nested foreach & if statements trying to echo a array value is confusing

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to compare 2 values from 2 arrays, 1 array is from an XML file and one is a global array.

I do not know the exact amounts and they do change over time, but for example,

The XML array has 100 values.
The global array has 5 values.

The comparison is for a simple text string, if they match echo "match" if not echo "no match".

The problem is, I can't figure out how to echo the proper value amounts without it looping through the foreach, instead of just printing "no match" once it will echo it 500 times.

I actually want the output to match the global array value, so in the instance echo "no match" 5 times.

It is probably something very fundamentally wrong with my approach as I am just learning.

```
$xml_string = simplexml_load_string($xml_body);

  // parse  XML feed 

    foreach ($xml_string->xpath('//plugin') as $character) {

        $xml_plugin_name = $character->name;

        $compare_value_remote = $xml_plugin_name;


   //grab the values we want from the global array     

        foreach ( $plugins as $key => $value ) {

         foreach ($value as $pkey){

          $plugin_name = $pkey["Name"];

          $compare_value_local =  $plugin_name;

    //compare them

             if( $compare_value_remote == $compare_value_local){

              echo "match";

             }else{

              echo "no match";

             }
           }             
       }
    }
```

Comment: You are right about one thing: this is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understood you correctly, you want to find the out if there is a match.

Try to look at this code

```
<?php

$xml_string = simplexml_load_string($xml_body);

foreach ($xml_string->xpath('//plugin') as $character)
        $xml_plugins[] = $character->name;

foreach ($plugins as $value) 
    foreach ($value as $pkey)
        $global_plugins[] = $pkey["Name"];

$matches = array_intersect($xml_plugins, $global_plugins);

if (count($matches) > 0) 
    echo "Match found";
else
    echo "No match found";

?>
```

Comment: I think this is more the direction I want to go, I just read about `array_intersect`. Using your code though I get match found when there are no actual matches, if I `print_r($matches)` the result is just `Array();` and var_dump gets me 0

Comment: Actually after reading that I think array_intersect is just returning no matches so there is no need to count, correct?

Comment: The statement `if (array() == true)` is true, so if you need to compare it to something, I think count() is necessary in this case

Answer (score 2):

Ragnar123'solution looks good, only one mistake makes you print "Match found" even if there is no match

```
if (count($matches > 0))
```

shoule be

```
if (count($matches) > 0)
```

because count(boolean) will return (int)1 so you'll always pass the if